# Tkinter binding between a Combobox and an entry box does nothing

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, binding, tkinter-entry

I am trying to build a small application to deploy among a few groups of engineers.  The application input includes the choice of a 2D or 3D model along with some characteristic lengths in the x,y and z directions.  If the user chooses a 2D model, I want the entry widget for the characteristic length in the z direction to become disabled.  I followed what I thought was right among several documentation web pages but nothing appears to work.  A snippet of my code is below.  Sorry that the code is not very pythonic.  I am an mechanical engineer who typically writes in FORTRAN and VB.  I am new to Python and am teaching myself.

```
#--------------------------------------
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import getcwd as cwd, path, remove

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Gaussian Random Field Generation and Analysis')
window.geometry('1150x800') 
title_label = tk.Label(window, text = 'Gaussian Random Field Tool', font=(None, 20)).place(x = 380, y = 0)
#--------------------------------------
btn_gen = tk.Button(window, text='Exit', width = 20, font=8, fg = 'blue',command = sys.exit)
btn_gen.place(x = 450, y = 750)
#--------------------------------------
#for generator placement
startx = 30
xoffset = 430
starty = 190
deltay = 40
#--------------------------------------
tk.Label(window, text='Gaussian Random Field Generator',font=50).place(x = 150, y = 100)
genframe = tk.Frame(window, width=525, height=540, highlightbackground = "black", highlightthickness = 1.0)
genframe.place(x = startx - 10, y = starty -50)
#---
#---
tk.Label(window, text='Characteristic z-direction length (fraction of total graph size):',font=8).place(x = startx, y = starty + 2 * deltay)
zlen_win = tk.Entry(window, width = 10)
zlen_win.insert(0, "0.1")
zlen_win.place(x = startx + xoffset, y = starty + 2 * deltay)
#---
def callback(dim):
    if dim == '3D':
        zlen_win.config(state = 'disabled')
    else:
        zlen_win.config(state = 'normal') 
tk.Label(window, text='Model dimension:',font=8).place(x=startx , y = starty - deltay )
model_dim = ('2D', '3D')
modeldim_cmb = ttk.Combobox(window, state = 'readonly', values = model_dim)
modeldim_cmb.current(0)
modeldim_cmb.place(x = startx + 0.815 * xoffset, y = starty - deltay)
dim = modeldim_cmb.get()
modeldim_cmb.bind('<Leave>', callback)
#--
tk.Label(window, text='Characteristic vertical length (fraction of total graph size):',font=8).place(x = startx, y = starty)
xlen_win = tk.Entry(window, width = 10)
xlen_win.insert(0, "0.1")
xlen_win.place(x = startx + xoffset, y = starty)
#---
tk.Label(window, text='Characteristic horizontal length (fraction of total graph size):',font=8).place(x = startx, y = starty + deltay)
ylen_win = tk.Entry(window, width = 10)
ylen_win.insert(0, "0.1")
ylen_win.place(x = startx + xoffset, y = starty + deltay)
#--
....
....
```

I fixed it!  It did turn out to be similar to what you said Brian.  Here is the updated code:

```
def callback(event):
    dim = modeldim_cmb.get()
    if dim == '3D':
        zlen_win.config(state = 'disabled')
    else:
        zlen_win.config(state = 'normal') 
tk.Label(window, text='Model dimension:',font=8).place(x=startx , y = starty - deltay )
model_dim = ('2D', '3D')
checkdim = tk.StringVar()
modeldim_cmb = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable = checkdim, state = 'readonly', values = model_dim)
modeldim_cmb.current(0)
modeldim_cmb.place(x = startx + 0.815 * xoffset, y = starty - deltay)
modeldim_cmb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback)
```

Comment: Have you examined what `dim` is inside of `callback` to see if it's what you're assuming it is?

Comment: When I put a simple print statement I get the initial value of the combobox, which is 2D.  It does not update and print if I change the combobox choice.  I looked at the similar answer above, but wouldn't the textvar in this case be the same as my dim value? I added a coupe of print statements in the callback definition.  I will print as soon as I run the code, but it will not print again. It seems like the code runs through everything initially, but will not rerun and call the callbackfunction when/if the combobox changes.

Comment: I fixed it!  It did turn out to be similar to what you said Brian.  Here is the updated code: